# bridge pattern C++ code compile error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, bridge

I am trying to compile a bridge pattern C++ sample code as mentioned [here](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge/cpp/1)

but I am getting compile errors when i do `g++ -o Bridge Bridge.C`

**Program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

class TimeImp {
  public:
    TimeImp(int hr, int min) {
        hr_ = hr;
        min_ = min;
    }
    virtual void tell() {
        cout << "time is " << setw(2) << setfill(48) << hr_ << min_ << endl; //error
    }
  protected:
    int hr_, min_;
};

class CivilianTimeImp: public TimeImp {
  public:
    CivilianTimeImp(int hr, int min, int pm): TimeImp(hr, min) {
        if (pm)
          strcpy(whichM_, " PM");
        else
          strcpy(whichM_, " AM");
    }

    /* virtual */
    void tell() {
        cout << "time is " << hr_ << ":" << min_ << whichM_ << endl;
    }
  protected:
    char whichM_[4];
};

class ZuluTimeImp: public TimeImp {
  public:
    ZuluTimeImp(int hr, int min, int zone): TimeImp(hr, min) {
        if (zone == 5)
          strcpy(zone_, " Eastern Standard Time");
        else if (zone == 6)
          strcpy(zone_, " Central Standard Time");
    }

    /* virtual */
    void tell() {
        cout << "time is " << setw(2) << setfill(48) << hr_ << min_ << zone_ << endl; //error
    }
  protected:
    char zone_[30];
};

class Time {
  public:
    Time(){}
    Time(int hr, int min) {
        imp_ = new TimeImp(hr, min);
    }
    virtual void tell() {
        imp_->tell();
    }
  protected:
    TimeImp *imp_;
};

class CivilianTime: public Time {
  public:
    CivilianTime(int hr, int min, int pm) {
        imp_ = new CivilianTimeImp(hr, min, pm);
    }
};

class ZuluTime: public Time {
  public:
    ZuluTime(int hr, int min, int zone) {
        imp_ = new ZuluTimeImp(hr, min, zone);
    }
};

int main() {
  Time *times[3];
  times[0] = new Time(14, 30);
  times[1] = new CivilianTime(2, 30, 1);
  times[2] = new ZuluTime(14, 30, 6);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    times[i]->tell();
}
```

**Error:**

> ]# g++ -o Bridge Bridge.C Bridge.C: In member function ‘virtual void
>   TimeImp::tell()’: Bridge.C:14: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in
>   ‘std::operator<< [with _CharT = char, _Traits =
>   std::char_traits](((std::basic_ostream >&)((std::basic_ostream >*)std::operator<< [with _Traits =
>   std::char_traits](((std::basic_ostream >&)(& std::cout)), ((const char*)"time is
>   ")))), std::setw(2)) << std::setfill with _CharT = int’
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/ostream.tcc:67: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char,
>   _Traits = std::char_traits] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/ostream.tcc:78: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT,
>   _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/ostream.tcc:90: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base&
>   (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits =
>   std::char_traits]

This is part of error, it extends with same pattern.

I've copy pasted the same code, analyzed the error lines but couldn't get it.

Can somebody please tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Maybe use a different design pattern? Try the adaptor first.

Comment: @juanchopanza i guess its not design pattern error, anyways I've tried adapter but on different code and it ran successfully

Comment: That's funny, your title and code sample seemed to indicate you were having a problem with the bridge pattern :-)

Comment: I think you misplaced your "std::"s.

Comment: yeah actually i just added for readers to know that i am implementing Bridge pattern, Also not completely sure whether or not its pattern error, because AFAIK the sourcemaking.com shows the o/p to be: `Outputtime is 1430
time is 2:30 PM
time is 1430 Central Standard Time`

Comment: You should take the habit to compile using `g++ -Wall -g`

Comment: Note that this error can be reproduced with the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) `#include <iostream> #include <iomanip> int main() { std::cout << std::setfill(4); }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::setfill` [takes a `char`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/), you are passing it an `int`.

Try:

```
cout << "time is " << setw(2) << setfill(' ') << hr_ << min_ << endl;
```

Comment: Isn't a character a number anymore? Did I miss something?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: `setfill(48)` will give the return type of `setfill<int>`, which is (probably) different to the return type of `setfill<char>` that `operator<<` expects.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : You're right, I focused on how to fix the error and not on explaining why the error was there (thanks Mike).